# Create Mysql View with parameters

Tags: mysql

I have a below "User_Info". It carries all user info and the ID of the company that each user belongs to.

```
User_Id    | User_Name | Company_Id  
-----------+-----------+--------------  
1002       | User1     | 113  
1003       | User2     | 114  
1004       | User3     | 111
```

I have another table "Company" which has Company Information and its associated Parent Company.

```
id  | Company_Name    | Parent_Company_Id  
----+-----------------+------------------ 
110 | WALMART         | NULL 
111 | WALMART TEXAS   | 110 
112 | WALMART DALLAS  | 111  
113 | WALMART HOUSTON | 111  
114 | WALMART KATY    | 113
```

Desired Output:

```
user_id  | company_id  
---------+--------------  
1002     | 113  
1002     | 111  
1002     | 110  
1003     | 114  
1003     | 111  
1003     | 110  
1004     | 111  
1004     | 110  


select user_id,  
       company_id  
from   (  
        select     u.id as user_id,  
                   c.id as company_id,  
                   c.parent_company_id,  
                   u.company_id as user_company_id  
        from       user_info u,  
                   company c  
        order by   1, 2 desc  
        limit      10000000000000000000 
       ) base  
where  company_id in (user_company_id, @p) 
and    if(@p := parent_company_id, 1, 1)
```

How do i convert the above query for my desired output as a MySql View?

Comment: Hello did you find a solution? Did you try with using a function?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW user_company_view AS
select user_id,  
       company_id  
from   (  
        select     u.id as user_id,  
                   c.id as company_id,  
                   c.parent_company_id,  
                   u.company_id as user_company_id  
        from       user_info u,  
                   company c  
        order by   1, 2 desc  
        limit      10000000000000000000 
       ) base  
where  company_id in (user_company_id, @p) 
and    if(@p := parent_company_id, 1, 1)
```

Comment: This is not a recursive query solution. The solution provided in my query works. The only problem is that i need to create a MySQL view but this select query has parameters which is not allowed during a View Creation. How do i change my query to a MySQl view?